# TypeError: askopenfilename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root' In [ ]:

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a code that opens a folder in the file explorer with a radiobutton. I found an example, but I got stuck on the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in    __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: askopenfilename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'
```

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog 
import tkinter.constants 

class filedialog(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        Radiobutton_opt = {'fill': tkinter.constants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse",  
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=2, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)
        self.file_opt = options = {}

        self.dir_opt = options = {} 
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Python Scripts'

    def askopenfilename(self, root):
        filename = filedialog().askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        if filename:
            return open(filename, 'r')

    def askdirectory(self, root):
        return filedialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    filedialog(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

The button does appear, but when I press it, I get the error. I'm new to python and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you are directly calling `self.askopenfilename` from the radiobutton without giving it the required argument. This is precisely what the error message is telling you.

Second, You have defined a class named `filedialog` that takes one parameter: `root`. *This class overrides the filedialog module*. Thus, from within `askopenfilename` you are making a recursive call to the very same `askopenfilename`, and are failing to provide the required argument since `self.file_opt` is an empty dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction. I kind of understand what you're saying, but I don't know how to implement this in my code. Could you add an example?

Comment: @Cucumber12: just remove `root` from `def askopenfilename(self, root)` since you never use it. Next, rename `filedialog` to something else.

Comment: I actually added the root in 'askopenfilename(self) to get rid of the error: 'TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root' ' I'm starting to think my code is no good:)

Comment: @Cucumber12: it is the call to `filedialog()` that is missing the `root` argument in that case. The problem is that you have two things named `filedialog` as your code is presented in the question, which is adding confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `askopenfilename(self, root)` function requires a root parameter but you didn't pass anything in your

```
tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text = "Browse",  
                command = self.askopenfilename
                ).grid( row=2, column =0, columnspan = 2, sticky =W)
```